# Combine 2 pythons functions

Tags: python

I have 2 separated functions that work pefectly but I can't combine them.
Here is the first one:

```
with open('/topladder/top_fr', 'r') as file1:
    with open('/topladder/top_pression', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

with open('/topladder/pr_top_fr', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

I have the good result on a file, a few lines and look like this:

```
#000000
#111111
#AAAAAA
```

The 2nd one extracts data from a JSON file and look like this:

```
    data = json.loads(response)

    for p in data ["items"]:
            if p["tag"] == #BBBBBB :
                print("%s %s %s" % (
                    p["rank"],
                    p["name"],
                    p["trophies"],
))
```

I get the good result too. However, instead puting the tag manually, I'd like to use the result of the first script and do something this way combinating both script:

```
with open('/topladder/top_fr', 'r') as file1:
    with open('/topladder/top_pression', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

    data = json.loads(response)

    for p in data ["items"]:
        for line in same:
            if p["tag"] == line :
                print("%s %s %s" % (
                    p["rank"],
                    p["name"],
                    p["trophies"],
))
```

However, No results... I guess i'm not so far
Thanks per advance !!

Comment: You have given two code snippets, not two functions. "script" and "function" are not synonyms in Python. As a first step, abstract both of those code snippets to actual functions, functions which have clearly-defined input parameters and that furthermore work by returning a value rather than printing it. Once you clear that hurdle, you can then worry about how to combine those two functions together into a single function.

Comment: ok, sorry for the wrong terms. However, wouldn't you have a solution instead to suggest please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` ends with a newline, you need to remove that before comparing with `p["tag"]`.

```
if p["tag"] == line.strip():
```

You can do this more efficiently by removing them when creating the set:

```
same = set(x.strip() for x in set(file1).intersection(file2))
```

There's also no need to loop through `same`, use `in`.

```
for p in data["items"]:
    if p["tag"] in same:
        print("%s %s %s" % (
            p["rank"],
            p["name"],
            p["trophies"],
        ))
```